# python to copy content of one column to other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to copy a content of a column in CSV to another CSV, I am trying below and its failing.

```
k1 = pd.DataFrame(k)
k1 = Dataframe['Category'] = Dataframe_name['Themes']
k1.to_csv(output_ticket_file)
```

Any pointers please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to move a column within the a CSV. In this case you can simply rename the column.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Read data.
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
# Copy column.
df["Themes"] = df["Category"]
# Modify data as needed.

df.to_csv("changed_data.csv")
```

Comment: @goe In case that did help, you can mark the answer as accepted. That's the best way of saying thank you on stack overflow ;)

Comment: Thank you @Jarno. I am trying to copy the content of a colum within same CSV. Category is existing column and Themes is new column which is copied.

Comment: @goe if I understand you correctly you want to copy the Themes column into the Category column. Is that right?

Comment: Category column to themes column within same CSV

Comment: Adapted the answer. Is renaming the column what you want?

Comment: rather renaming column if you can help me how to copy the content in different column as I have to remove duplicates in new column(Themes) and retain existing (Category)

Comment: In that case the now adapted answer should work. If that does not satisfy your needs, you can edit your original question, to make it more clear what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

To copy one column from a dataframe to another is really easy:

```
#existing dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

#new dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

#copy data from existing to new
#let a new column for df2 be called X
df2['X'] = df['A']
```